# the right way to do deployment with capistrano

Tags: security, ssh, capistrano, deployment

I look for good practices for deploying with capistrano.

I would like to start out with a short description how I used to do deployment.

capistrano is installed locally on a developer's computer. I deploy thought gateway with capistrano option `:gateway`. Firstly, I thought that with `:gateway` option I need to have ssh connection only to gateway host, but it turns out that I need ssh connection (*public key*) to all hosts where I want to deploy to.

I would like to find a convenient and secure way to deploy application.

For example, in case when new developer starts working, is much more convinient to put his *public_key* only on gateway server and not on all applications servers. On the other hand I don't want him to have any connection to servers in particular *ssh* to gateway, just because he is developer, he needs to do only deployments.

If you are aware of good practices for deploying with capistrano, please, let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano is designed from the bits out on the assumption that ssh is the basis for all management. The machine used as a gateway has to both accept and issue ssh connections. There is no away around that. Your developers will get ssh access to the gateway.

You have some requirements:

- Ease of adding new developers to the authorized-keys list of your deployment targets
- Do not want to give developers a full terminal on the gateway box

You need to decide how you're going to handle keying on your deployment targets. You have two major options here:

1. Use a generic key, everyone gets one and that's baked into the image/targets.
2. Use specific keys, everyone gets their own and you manage the authorized_keys list through something like [puppet](/questions/tagged/puppet) or [chef](/questions/tagged/chef).

The second option is the most secure, but works best if you have a configuration management system in place. You really should use one, and it can even supply the authorized_keys file for the gateway server.

You have some options for restricting what developers can do once they ssh into your system.

- [Restricting SSH shell access to Debian server](https://serverfault.com/questions/86216/restricting-ssh-shell-access-to-debian-server)
- [Custom Openssh Shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/436642/custom-openssh-shell)
- [How to restrict the users' shell allowing to execute shell programs](https://serverfault.com/questions/89778/how-to-restrict-the-users-shell-allowing-to-execute-shell-programs)

Depending on how Capistrano actually works with a gateway, some of these may prevent it from working so testing is in order. It may be that a full shell is required for it to function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer, as I understood I need to maintain all users public keys only on gateway or on all app hosts (If I maintain keys on gateway do I need alter somehow ssh setting)? What's preferable to do among to following options: doing deployment locally from the host of every developer or I can ask them to ssh to gateway and doing deployment from the gateway.

Comment: Going the gateway route allows you to firewall off your production environment from everything but the gateway; safer overall that way. The most recommended key-management strategy is to have all the dev keys on both gateway and prod boxes, and rely on `ssh-agent` forwarding. Their priv-keys are kept on their own boxes, but ssh-agent on their own box and the gateway forwards the keys to the prod boxes.